# LazyLoading not work if use primary key as string

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading, .net-6.0

I have these three models

```
public class Resposta
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PerguntaAlias { get; set; }
        public virtual Pergunta Pergunta { get; set; }
        public int JustificativaId  { get; set; }
        public virtual Justificativa Justificativa { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

public class Justificativa
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NumeroOC { get; set; }
        public string Objeto { get; set; }
    }
public class Pergunta
    {     
        [Key]
        public string Alias { get; set; }        
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
        public Subcategoria? Subcategoria { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Obrigatório")]
        public bool Obrigatorio { get; set; }
    }
```

But when i try to use lazyloading with "Resposta", it only works with the model "Justificativa", the model "Pergunta" is null.

I dont know if it happens because the primary key of "Pergunta" is a string.

Here is a pic of the issue: [image]

I dont wanna use "Include", why is it happenning? (The FK's on DB are OK)

Comment: Do you have a [mre]. Works just fine for me (though I use 7th version).

Answer (score 1):

Was not able to reproduce. Based on type shown in the debugger you don't actually have lazy loading enabled otherwise I would be expecting type for `Justificativa` to be something like `JustificativaProxy`. The effect you see is just result of relationship fix up due to change tracking - it seems that you have previously loaded an instance of `Justificativa` (the one which you use for Id filtering).

Be sure to install [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) and call `UseLazyLoadingProxies` when setting up `DbContextOptions`:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(b => b.Use...(...)
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
```

Read more:

- [Lazy Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy)
- [Change Tracking in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)
- [Relationship fixup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#relationship-fixup)

Comment: Yes I agree. But I have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies installed, and it works for another model (debugger shows ...Proxy), but I don't know why with this model it doesn't work. Anyway, I used the .Include to not get stuck in that

Comment: @SauloTorres based on the provided screenshot there is no lazy loading happening for both relations.